# Is this theorem on product of metric spaces correct?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

[image]

This is from a text on metric spaces. Having studied topology before, I don't think the statement is correct. Cartesian product of open sets from X and Y should only give us a basis for the product topology, but cannot give us the entire set of open sets. Unless I am remembering something wrong, the same should be true for metric spaces as well.

[image]

Edit: As some comments have pointed out, the theorem is incorrect, so I decided to post the entire proof to figure out where the proof is wrong.

Comment: You are correct: the theorem is false. A set $G\subseteq X\times Y$ is open in the product iff it is a **union** of sets of the form $G_1\times G_2$ such that $G_1$ is open in $X$, and $G_2$ is open in $Y$.

Comment: What text is this?

Comment: An introduction to metric spaces by Dhanajay Gopal. I was looking for a text just about metric spaces

Comment: @BrianM.Scott i am going to post the proof anyway, as I am curious where the proof went wrong.

Comment: @William: The final step is false in general. It can fail even for a union of two sets of the form $A\times B$: $(0,2)\cup(1,3)=(0,3)$, but $$\big((0,2)\times(0,2)\big)\cup\big((1,3)\times(1,3)\big)\ne(0,3)\times(0,3)\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the last equation.

[image]

In the RHS the author suspiciously does not specify over which $x$ and $y$ those unions range. If we try to fill them in, the problem becomes apparent: We have
$$\left(\bigcup_{x\in G_X} A_x\right)\times \left(\bigcup_{y\in G_Y} B_y\right) = \bigcup_{(x,y)\in G_X\times G_Y} A_x \times B_y$$
so the last equation is true **if $G$ is of the form $G=G_X\times G_Y$ for some sets $G_X \subseteq X$ and $G_Y \subseteq Y$**, but it is not true in general.

Answer (score 0):

$(A \times B)\cup (C \times D) \subseteq (A\cup C)\times (B\cup D)$. I think the proof is wrong in the second last line where it is written $G=\bigcup_{x,y \in G}(B_X(x,r)\times B_Y(y,r))$ "=" $\cdots$.